# A scraping issue on C# scraping project

Tags: c#, selenium, web-scraping

I wish everybody has a good day!
I am new to building scraping project in c#.
Now I am trying to scrape the content of a tag href property from a web-site.
but could not come to good conclusion yet!
Here is the structure of web-page:

```
<table class="matches date_matches grouped">
    <thead></thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr id="date_matches-16-53658" class="group-head clickable" stage-value="212">
            <th colspan="5">
            </th>
            <th class="competition-link">
             <a href="/national/south-africa/psl/20192020/regular-season/r53038/"><span>More…</span></a>
            </th>
        </tr>
        <tr id="xxx">
            ...
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I am going to scrape the content of href url-link string (Here: "/national/south-africa/psl/20192020/regular-season/r53038/").
Here is my c# scraping project:

```
using OpenQA.Selenium;
using OpenQA.Selenium.Chrome;
...
IWebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
driver.Navigate().GoToUrl("https://....");
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> alinks = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("//td[@class='score-time']/a[contains(@href, 'south-africa')]"));
```

I tried in some other ways for scraping the content of href property.
but still not get the correct result.
Thanks in good advice!!!

Answer (score 0):

please try this code it will help you.

```
public string FindHref()
{
     string href = string.Empty;
     List<IWebElement> anchors = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a")).ToList();
     for (int i = 0; i < anchors.Count; i++)
     {
         href = anchors[i].GetAttribute("href");
     }
     return href;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one

```
var linkList = new List<string>();
var links = Driver.FindElements(By.CssSelector("a"));
var linkList = linkList.AddRange(links.Select(link => link.GetAttribute("href")));
```